# How to access to "platform-api"?

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I am trying to develop a user space code for the following platform :

Nexus 5 + UbuntuTouch + ubuntu 15.04  Vivid

Can i access to "platform-api" functions of the operating system? and how?

Comment: https://www.kernel.org/doc/htmldocs/kernel-api/ your question is too broad

Comment: The question is not too broad. It is asking about using the APIs of https://launchpad.net/platform-api in an application made for the Ubuntu phone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that any of these sorts of APIs which are usable, are exposed at higher level via the QML SDK. Not all APIs are usable in production apps which you wish to ship in the store, however, due to security and privacy concerns and restrictions in the system.

If you aren't planning to release your app into the *Ubuntu Store*, then you can basically use any of the APIs you wish, but you may need to install additional packages in the build environment, in order to build your app. You will also need to declare the security profile as *unconfined* (this will result in your app being flagged for manual review if you attempt to upload it to the Ubuntu Store site, and it's unlikely such an app would be approved).

Comment: Much appreciate for the answer. Would you please give me an example for installing additional packages? where I can get those packages and how they are installed? are they installed on the development host computer? the build environment is formed inside a container as far as I know. How I can install a package inside a container?